# Naming Python class similar to reserved keyword `Class`

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, naming

Is it 'ok'/legal in Python to name a class 'Class' for a group of students, and will that cause any syntactic problems?

NB I'm aware that:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

my_class = Class()
```

won't throw an error, but will it cause potential issues in extended use?

Potential issues I can imagine are problems with linters/parses that might use/run on the code. Is my presumption that Python's internals won't have a problem?

I've searched SO and Google, but has difficulty getting results due to the obvious term clash, and many tutorials containing `class Student`. 
I did find PEP8 referring to name collisions between arguments and reserved keywords, advising appending an underscore to the offending argument.
I also see a more stylistic objection to the obvious name collision, and that while Class methods would be methods of Class, they would not be classmethods (although I can't find a PEP8 prohibition), but acknowledge that that is opinion and thus outside the bounds of SO.

Comment: By convention anything that starts with an uppercase letter is usually a class, so while it still may be confusing to some, I think to experienced Python programmers or anyone working with an editor that has syntax highlighting should be fine.

Comment: Also, no reasonably linter is going to do `if token.lower() == 'class': # parse class`, and `'c' != 'C'`, so I doubt you'll break any linters or parsers.

Comment: Fair enough. While I *assumed* it would be fine because of the lack of error, it was suggested to me that this would be a good question, as it will surely be asked again. I'm sure someone can answer more adequately than I, though, although I'll answer myself if noone does in a couple of days.

Comment: I'm in the same boat here sorta. I would rather leave my answer as comment, and see what others have to say, relatively uninfluenced. I'm sure there are plenty of people who will argue against using `Class` due to confusion, but I want to see if there are any other points to be made.

Comment: Well sure, that's my objection, but Form/Period aren't very clear in my use case, and bloated alternatives like `GroupofSudents` or `StudentGroup` together with a `Student` class seemed just as bad.

Comment: Could `Course` be an alternative?

Comment: Not clarity wise, to me, although that one didn't occur to me. My application takes groups of students (ie a class) and displays their scores using avatars. Mrs A's Trig102 and Mr B's Trig102 aren't different courses.

Comment: I see. What about `Classmates`, if it only concerns the grouping of students? Of `CourseClass` if you need the course info too. Or `SchoolClass`.

Comment: Honestly I think `Class` is fine for a, well, class.  It's not a syntax error, not worth overthinking it.

Comment: `Class` is a fine, legal and totally appropriate name for a group(/set/list/etc.) of `Students`, and will not cause semantic problems. ((The only way it could ever get ambiguous or confuse users is generic or internal names @classmethod, internals like `Class.__class__`, or if someone wrote a `ClassFactory`, etc. I was the person who [pointed out that Class methods would be methods of Class, they would not be classmethods](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45591468#45591468). But anyway none of these are objections to `Class` being a fine and legal name, which it is.)

Comment: Someone might quibble by citing one recommendation from ['Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin: "Use searchable/search-friendly names"](https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c), but in this case the enormous clarity benefit outweighs that objection; and in any case we can search for the unambiguous phrase "class Class", and/or do a case-sensitive search for Python references to Class.

Comment: @DillonDavis if you've time to submit an answer, fell free. I don't think I'll have time to write something I'm happy with this week.

Answer (score 0):

In summary - `Class` is perfectly legal and should not cause any issues to Python. as Python is case sensitive. Any (sensible) linter or IDE should thus not have a problem with its usage as an identifier.